# can I output to file with screen command?

Tags: linux

A quick question about screen.

I am wondering if it is possible for me to output to file when running a command via screen

for example I have tried

```
screen -d -m -S mycommand >/tmp/output
```

but this does not work.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manpage:

> `-L`   tells screen to turn on automatic output logging for the windows.

It looks like you're running non-interactively, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd> presumably won't work for you.

Comment: +1 The log file is called `screenlog.0` and is located in the directory you ran `screen` from.